# In VIew how to use ViewModel with ViewModelProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, view-model-pattern

Here is my MineSweeperView class:

```kotlin
class MineSweeperView : View {

constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    private var userViewModel: UserViewModel


    init {
        ....
        userViewModel = ViewModelProvider(???).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

ViewModelProvider(*this*) and (*context*) is not working in View class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. It would be improper for a View to have a ViewModel class. ViewModels are only for LifecycleOwners, because they are scoped to the life of a LifecycleOwner. That's the whole reason for the existence of ViewModel, to have it's life controlled by the life of some other lifecycle object.